# Angular reactive form custom validation : update on change not working on first time

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have implemented a custom validation in my reactive form, basically, it will show an error when the length of the field reaches a certain limit.

```
this.formGroup = new FormBuilder().group({
     comment: [null, {
        validators: [ValidateCommentLength],
        updateOn: 'change'
      }]
  })
```

HTML

```
<textarea
            autocomplete="off"
            maxlength="3600"
            nxInput
            (ngModelChange)="valueChange($event)"
            type="text"
            [formControlName]="'comment'"
          ></textarea>
          <nx-error nxFormfieldError *ngIf="formGroup.get('comment').invalid" appearance="text">
            Maximum comment length is exceeded 
          </nx-error>
        </nx-formfield>
```

But the validation is not triggering on the first time of input change on the later changes it will work

**UPDATE Validator**

```
import { AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';

const MAX_LENGTH =  2;

    export function ValidateCommentLength(control: AbstractControl) {
    
        if (control.value) {
            if (!control.value.replace(/\s/g, '').length) {
                return null;
            }
            const  remaining = MAX_LENGTH - control.value.length;
            if (!remaining || Math.sign(remaining) === -1) {
                return { CommentError: true };
           }
    
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Please add code for ValidateCommentLength

Comment: [I reproduce your scenario](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ameawh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts), what's wrong?

Comment: @OwenKelvin added validator

Comment: @MehdiShakeri  that's not correct I have custom form validator, Please check the updated question

Comment: @iambatman which library is `nx-error` from?

Comment: @OwenKelvin Thats an external library https://aposin.github.io/ng-aquila

Comment: [pls check it](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ameawh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Seems like an issue with the error component @MehdiShakeri thanks for the  help

Comment: Why dont you just create a Form Control and use your custom validator on it? Like     `this.myAwesomeFormControl.setValidators(myCustomValidator());`. Dont forget to update the Form Control after it: `this.myAwesomeFormControl.updateValueAndValidity();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The problem

The problem is that `nx-error` will only show if the input is touched. But input is only touched when we blur out of the form

### Solution

After the validator invalidates the input, trigger touched manually

```typescript
export function ValidateCommentLength(control: AbstractControl) {
  if (control.value) {
    if (!control.value.replace(/\s/g, "").length) {
      return null;
    }
    const remaining = MAX_LENGTH - control.value.length;
    if (!remaining || Math.sign(remaining) === -1) {
      control.markAsTouched()
      return { CommentError: true };
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

In the above I have just added `control.markAsTouched()` and now validation works as you expect

[See Demo Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qpsbzj-yddacj)